# PHP7.0-curl and MSSQL Tools Incompatibility

Tags: 18.04, curl, php7, mssql

I'm trying to install Moodle on Ubuntu 18.04 and connect it to a MSSQL server.

But when i try to install php7.0-curl extension, so moodle can work, the MSSQL Tools and other libs are being deleted cause they support `libcurl3` although the latest `php7.0-curl` has a dependency only with `libcurl4`.

So when i try to install `libcurl4` it removes the packages MSSQL tools and others.

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql mssql-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl3 msodbcsql17
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev php7.0-curl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3 msodbcsql msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Is there any way to install older `php7.0-curl` extension so i can keep both MSSQL tools and Moodle happy?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install previous version of extensions *‘common’* and *‘curl’* for php7.0

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-common_7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-curl_7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb


sudo dpkg -i php7.0-common_7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb


sudo dpkg -i php7.0-curl_7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
```